# TYPO3 add css if GET var is not empty

Tags: css, typo3

My goal is quite simple. If a certain GET parameter is not empty in the URL of the present page I'd like to inject some css to it.

In the example bellow I'd like to hide everything (just for example proposes) if the `tx_multishop_pi1[page_section]` exists in the URL.

```
page{
  headerData.960= TEXT
  headerData.960.data = GP:tx_multishop_pi1|page_section
  headerData.960.required = 1
  headerData.960.value(
  <style type="text/css">
  body{
    display:none !important;
  }
  </style>
  )       
}
```

But this isn't working. I could try `[globalString = GP:tx_multishop_pi1|page_section = somehting]` but I don't want that. I want to inject css if the `tx_multishop_pi1[page_section]` var exists (no meter its value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `userFunc` condition (on the bottom of the [TSref Conditions](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.7.0/view/1/4/)) to perform (almost) any comparison.

The most important thing to remember is that this function must to begin with `user_` prefix, there are some old docs, which doesn't mention that or gives wrong samples. Here's a sample for you (add it to `localconf.php`)

```
function user_multishopSectionExists() {
    $gp = t3lib_div::_GP('tx_multishop_pi1');
    return (is_array($gp) && array_key_exists('page_section', $gp)) ? true : false;
}
```

So you can use it in the TS setup field:

```
[userFunc = user_multishopSectionExists()]
  page.headerData.960= TEXT
  page.headerData.960.value(
    // etc...
  )
[end]
```

*Of course it is better idea to write general matcher ie. something like:*

```
[userFunc = user_paramExists("tx_multishop_pi1|page_section")]
```

Answer (score 2):

this can be done by using `globalString` condition and `if.isTrue.data`

```
[globalString = GP:tx_multishop_pi1|page_section > 0]
    page.headerData.960 = TEXT
    page.headerData.960 {
        value (
            <style>
                body{
                   display:none !important;
                }
            </style>
        )
       if.isTrue.data = GP:tx_multishop_pi1|page_section
    }
[end]
```